# Any way to show a view only once the app is used?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uipicker

I am creating an app which requires the users to enter certain values when the app is used for the first time.
A settings screen with 4 UITextFields and a UIPicker.
This settings view can be accessed later using a button from the mainscreen.
Somebody please suggest some ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NSUserDefaults and set a BOOL or a NSDate to indicate that you app has been used for the first time.

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstUse"]`